# Graph api paging is wrong... Why?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, paging

I'm building a facebook albums/photos browser.
The facebook api provides a cool paging system that is supposed to avoid us to build it.
However it doesn't seem to work properly...
Have a look at this query:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums

It returns all albums for the current user. However, it displays a previous and next paging although there are albums only on the next page (previous page is empty...)

Any idea why is this happening ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook usually doesn't bother determining if there is data in the next or previous query. It just automatically builds the url for you based on what the current query is.

A common sight in FB development:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

It's up to you to decode the response and see if it is an empty array. In this case, you are on the first page, so you should expect the Previous link to return an empty dataset.

Comment: I found the same problem. You have to waste another second or two for an empty request...